# Ejabberd 13.x store messages in mysql database

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

I have been looking at [mod_archive2](http://www.ndl.kiev.ua/content/modarchive2-status) but the problem is it still doesn't support the latest 13.x branch of eJabberd. Is there any alternative to saving all conversation of ejabberd into the database so I can also use it on my website?

note by the dev:

> Also note that ejabberd 13.x branch is currently not supported, and I don’t have any immediate plans to support it.

Comment: if u find your solution please post it as answer, it would be very helpful for us.

Comment: @Anurag I resorted to using and modifying openfire from source. Then finally settled to writing my own implementation of a xmpp server with the help of node-xmpp in node-js.